# Find common elements in multiple lists and delete data if they match in Python

Tags: python, list, set

I have a document with many pages, and I am trying to extract the first 3 lines of each page.

I do this and my output is multiple lists, for example:

```
['hello','','data']
['hello','','data']
['test','','data']
```

I want to remove any matching lists, for example, page 1 and page 2 have the same 3 lines. I want to delete theses 3 lines from the original document for the relevant pages. How could I go about doing this?

So far, I have tried using the set and intersection function. Example:

```
for item in line_list:
    common = list(set(line_list[0]).intersection(line_list[2:]))
    print (common)
```

All I get here are empty lists. I think it may be my syntax but not sure. Can anyone please advise?

Comment: you want to remain only with ['hello','','data'], ['test','','data']? can't realy understand what you are trying to achieve

Comment: No, I want to delete the common lists from my full page of data. So if there is no common pages with ```['test','','data']``` this list can remain and the loop will check the next page of the document

Answer (score 0):

`set.intersection` doesn't take an iterable of iterables (which it looks like you're trying to pass), but it does allow an arbitrary number of arguments, which it expects to be iterables.

Try:

```
common = list(set(line_list[0]).intersection(*line_list[2:]))
```

Google for "splat operator python" for more information on what `*` does.

Comment: This may not answer what you're trying to do overall, but it should indicate to you the proper usage of `set.intersection` so that at least you can properly assess its usefulness in your specific situation.

Answer (score 0):

There's a function called `set` in python that returns a collection with unique values or tuples of a list. The problem is you have a list of lists. So in order to do that you must transform your list into a tuple, then use set to get the unique lists, and then transform it again into a list. And that is how you do it:

```
a = ['hello','','data']
b = ['hello','','data']
c = ['test','','data']

common = [list(x) for x in set(tuple(x) for x in [a, b, c])]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you know where the duplicate is, you can slice in an intelligent manner to get rid of the redundancies.
You can use the readlines() command:

`lines_without_redundancy = all_lines[3::]`

Comment: That approach doesn't work in all cases, only in the cases you know exactly where the duplicate is.

Comment: As mentioned in my answer: 'Assuming that you know where the duplicate is[...]', you can certainly make it work that way.